# Making a tkinter window acessible to Windows narrator

Tags: python, tkinter, ocr, narrator

I was wondering if i could output something that the windows narrator can use to narrate my tkiner application.

```
import tkinter as tk
 
# create root window
root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Test")

 
lbl = tk.Label(root, text = "A label")
lbl.grid()
 
root.mainloop()
```

Taking this as a example, lets say a mouse is hovering over the label, the narraor will read, "A label".

There are methods for doing optical text recognition through pip libraries, but I was wondering if I could do ocr without downloading modules, and through the use of windows narrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pywin32` package, with SAPI SpVoice.

I have bound the `<Enter>` attribute to speak whenever you hover over the label. You could of course use different triggers if you so desire.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import win32com.client

# create root window
root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Test")

lbl = tk.Label(root, text="A label")
lbl.grid()

speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")

lbl.bind("<Enter>", lambda _: speaker.Speak(lbl.cget("text")))

root.mainloop()
```

If you want to generalise this solution such that all your labels are narrated, you could subclass the `tk.Label`, like so

```py
import tkinter as tk
import win32com.client

speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")


class NarratedLabel(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Enter>", lambda _: speaker.Speak(self.cget("text")))


# create root window
root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Test")


lbl = NarratedLabel(root, text="A label")
lbl.grid()

lbl2 = NarratedLabel(root, text="Another label")
lbl2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```